# How to build tag hierarchy on rails using acts-as-taggable-on

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, hierarchy, tagging, acts-as-taggable-on

I have a rails app that includes tagging for blog posts using the gem acts-as-taggable-on. My idea is to extend the tagging mechanism of this gem using a moderate-link approach where I can choose to create a few users as tag owners and they can choose to link one tag to another as parent/child.

Presently the system has independent tags like `Education`,  `Child Education` and `Distance Education`

The tag owner of `Education` can choose to select `Child Education` and `Distance Education`
as first level child and link them together. This relationship wont be visible until its approved by the Taxonomist(A tag administrator).

Similarly, an end user can also suggest `Distance Education` tag to be the child of `Education` and this request will become visible to the tag administrator. Based on his approval the relationship will be established.

These are the few questions I have pertaining to the requirement above:-

1. Is it recommended to extended the gem or should I use an independent tagging model written from scratch to support this hierarchical system ?
2. If I go ahead with the schema provided by the gem , what kind of a model should be used to design such a requirement.  Specifically, should I use a single table with a parent_id column with the tag id and tag name ? Or should I maintain their relationship in a separate table with many-to-many associations (tag_id, parent_tag_id (as Foreign key)).
3. I am also new to data structures so I will need some initial inputs on the choice of algorithms to efficiently traverse between a tag family. Using linked list was one my options however considering Rails mantra of convention over configuration , I am really unsure of how to proceed on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember doing something similir like 4 years ago with [ActsAsTree](https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree).

There s also an example of how to do it manually [here](http://blog.hashrocket.com/posts/recursive-sql-in-activerecord).

Both options will need that parent_id column on your tags table and are really straightforward. Just create a tag.rb in your models folder and extend Tag class.

Ps. Its been a long time, but i remember having to check that there are no loops, just keep it in mind

Comment: Thanks Trompa. I think this answer addresses most of my concerns.

Comment: @Trompa - No Loops? What does that mean exactly?

Comment: Loops on the tree you create through parent_id. You can potentially do something like A -> B, B -> C, C -> A. ( C.parent_id = B, B. Parent_id = A, A.parent_id = C )